# How to create .profile file and where it should be saved

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, path, .profile

Iam very new to Mac OS X 10.6.2 ,i want to create java_home and path. I find that those will be defined in .profile file, how can i create it and where should it be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any text editor - TextEdit, f/ex.  Create the file in your home folder.  (TextEdit will warn you about creating files whose names begin with '.'. Tell it to do it anyway.)